# count failed login attempts in Cakephp

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1, brute-force

i am working on a cakephp 2.x. i am using auth component .. i want to ask if that possible in auth component to track the user fail login attempts and also i have searched on google and i found this component

http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/aep_/2006/11/04/brute-force-protection

should i use this in my cakephp 2.3 .is that component is compatible for 2.3 ?i want to prevent my app from brute force attact. so is this component is  perfect for me ? or if there is any else good component there too or a better approach to handle the brute force?

Answer (score 2):

No, that is a bad approach IMO.

First use blowfish or some sort of hashing with "slow encryption". That is the most important base factor.

Then don't use Session, IP or other easily spoofable data to secure your login, but the actual user record the user wants to login as. This way the attacker cannot influence the amount of login attempts by changing his IP or other identification features. It also protects better against bot net attacks (using multiple computers at once).

So if he tries to login as "carl", count the logins made to this specific account and black hole if too many requests are made within a specific time (temporary disable login for this account). He can still run through all users this way, of course, but he will never ever be able to actually brute force the user. 
You should "enable login" for this user again, though, after a specific period of time.

Comment: sir thankyou for your detailed explanation .. sir i dont how to blackhole it and how to calculate time period.. can you write some pseudo-code or an example code so i can use your approach ..

Comment: Use Captcha code to humanize after 3 or 4 attempts is also a good idea

Comment: @VahidAlimohamadi i have captcha already i just want to count the login attempts so for example if login failed after three attempts i will show the captcha but dont know how to count